# Issue with my if else statement in a do while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

My do-while loop is supposed to print out numbers from 1 - 106 (including 1 and 106)

whats supposed to happen:
multiples of 3 are supposed to print out Big,
multiples of 5 are supposed to print out Mean,
multiples of 7 are supposed to print out Bugs,
multiples of 3 and 5 are supposed to print out BigMean,
multiples of 3 and 7 are supposed to print out BigBugs,
multiples of 5 and 7 are supposed to print out MeanBugs,
multiples of 3, 5 and 7 are supposed to print out BigMeanBugs.

What actually happens:
my do-while loop only runs the first "if" statement. Any help?

My code:

```java
public static void main(String [] args){
      
    int i = 0;      
    do{
        ++i;
        if(i %3 == 0){
            System.out.print("Big, ");
             
            if(i %5 ==0){
                System.out.print("Mean, ");
            }
            if(i %7 ==0){
                System.out.print("Bugs, "); 
            }
            if((i %3 == 0) && (i %5 == 0)){
                System.out.print("BigMean, ");
            }
            if((i %3 == 0) && (i %7 == 0)){
                System.out.print("BigBugs, ");
            }
               
        }else if((i %5 == 0) && (i %7 == 0)){
            System.out.print("MeanBugs, ");
               
        }else if((i %3 == 0) && (i %5 == 0) && (i %7 ==0)){
            System.out.print("BigMeanBugs, ");
                     
        }else{
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }               
    }while(i<=106);   
            
}//closing main
```

Comment: It runs only first because other statements are inside of block of that statement

Comment: I have run the code locally and get this out put: `1 2 Big, 4 5 Big, 7 8 Big, 10 11 Big, 13 14 Big, Mean, BigMean, 16 17 Big, 19 20 Big, Bugs, BigBugs, 22 23 Big, 25 26 Big, 28 29 Big, Mean, BigMean, 31 32 Big, 34 MeanBugs, Big, 37 38 Big, 40 41 Big, Bugs, BigBugs, 43 44 Big, Mean, BigMean, 46 47 Big, 49 50 Big, 52 53 Big, 55 56 Big, 58 59 Big, Mean, BigMean, 61 62 Big, Bugs, BigBugs,` ... and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As I could see your problem is probably that your *if-statements* are inside of first *if-statement*, so maybe you want this:

```java
public class BigMeanBugsDoWhileLoop
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
  
    int i = 0;  
    
    do
    {
        ++i;
        boolean bug = false;
        String result = "";

        if(i %3 == 0)
        {
            result += "Big";
            bug = true;
        }
        
        if(i %5 ==0)
        {
            result += "Mean";
            bug = true;
        }
        
        if(i %7 ==0)
        {
            result += "Bugs";
            bug = true;
        }
        
        if(!bug)
        {
           System.out.println(i + "");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println(result);
        }
    }while(i<106);   
        
  }//closing main
 
} // closing class
```

You don't need other *if-statements* because you don't use `break` so other expressions will be evaluated before next iteration.

Comment: Nice idea!  Eliminates unnecessary code.  But instead of a `boolean` you could just use the `result.isEmpty()` test.to control the printing.

Answer (score 2):

- First, if something is divisible by 3 and 7 it is divisible by 21.
- Second, if you reverse the order, you will catch divisible by 3 and 5 before divisible by 3 or 5 separately (assuming that is what you want).  If you do it the other way you may print the values prematurely or miss them altogether before checking the other possible factors.  This behavior is also dependent on `if` vs `if/else if` statements.

I have limited the printout to 25 to avoid a long list. Modify as you see fit.

```
public class BigMeanBugsDoWhileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        do {
            String bugType = "";
            if (i % 105 == 0) {
                bugType = "BigMeanBugs";  // 3 5 7
            } else if (i % 35 == 0) {
                bugType = "MeanBugs";     // 5 7 
            } else if (i % 21 == 0) {   
                bugType = "BigBugs";      // 3 7
            } else if (i % 15 == 0) {
                bugType = "BigMean";      // 3 5
            } else if (i % 7 == 0) {       
                bugType = "Bugs";         // 7
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                bugType = "Mean";         // 5
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                bugType = "Big";          // 3
            }
            System.out.println(bugType.isEmpty() ? i : bugType);
            i++;
        } while (i <= 25);
        
    }// closing main
    
} // closing class
```

Prints this.

```
1
2
Big
4
Mean
Big
Bugs
8
Big
Mean
11
Big
13
Bugs
BigMean
16
17
Big
19
Mean
BigBugs
22
23
Big
Mean
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to  increment  the value of i in the end of loop

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  
     int i = 1;
     
     do{   
        
        if(i %3 == 0){
          System.out.print("Big, ");
         
           if(i %5 ==0){
             System.out.print("Mean, ");
           }
              if(i %7 ==0){
                System.out.print("Bugs, "); 
              }
                 if((i %3 == 0) && (i %5 == 0)){
                   System.out.print("BigMean, ");
                 }
                    if((i %3 == 0) && (i %7 == 0)){
                      System.out.print("BigBugs, ");
                    }
           
                    }else if((i %5 == 0) && (i %7 == 0)){
                      System.out.print("MeanBugs, ");
           
                 }else if((i %3 == 0) && (i %5 == 0) && (i %7 ==0)){
                   System.out.print("BigMeanBugs, ");
                 
           }else{
             System.out.print(i + " ");
           }
           i++;
        }while(i<=106);

        
     }//closing main
 
  } // closing class
```

Comment: Incremented on beginning of loop. This is not solution

Comment: it gives me the same answer as my original code ):

Comment: @OriannaSanele I mentioned, you put everything in first if statement, please improve formating it will be easier for everyone including you to find mistake, or reread code.